# Extent reports - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: VERSION_2_3_23

Tags: extentreports

While running the below code I found following exception. Please help me to resolve the issue. I tried with changing freemaker jar files too.

```
public class sample1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new 
        ExtentHtmlReporter("extent.html");
        ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
        ExtentTest test = extent.createTest("MyFirstTest", "Sample description");
        test.log(Status.INFO, "This step shows usage of log(status, details)");
        test.info("This step shows usage of info(details)");

        MediaEntityBuilder
            .createScreenCaptureFromPath("screenshot.png")
            .build());
        test.addScreenCaptureFromPath("screenshot.png");
        extent.flush();
    }
}
```

Error details:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: VERSION_2_3_23
at com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentHtmlReporter.start(ExtentHtmlReporter.java:93)
at com.aventstack.extentreports.Report.attach(Report.java:55)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
at com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports.attachReporter(ExtentReports.java:68)
at com.br.mainsript.sample1.main(sample1.java:23)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the current version 3 of the community edition.  The version you have does not support the reporter attachments.  Below is the maven depenency:

```
<!-- pom.xml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Just i upgraded my eclipse version from Juno to latest oxygen and found that issue is rrsolved. Issue due to java complier version. When I upgraded to jre8 it is working fine.